# How do you prove that $A-B$ is bounded given that $A$ and $B$ are bounded subsets of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $A-B$ is bounded given that $A$ and $B$ are bounded subsets of reals.

**My attempt:** since sets $A$ and $B$ are bounded there exists an $m$, $n$ such that $|a|\le m$ for all $a\in A$ and $|b|\le n$ for all $b\in B$ respectively. Then $m-n$ is such that $|x|\le m-n$ for all $x\in A-B$. This proves that $A-B$ is bounded.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. If, say, $m=1$ and $n=2$, then you are claiming that $x\in A\setminus B\implies|x|\leqslant-1$. This is clearly false (unless $A-B=\emptyset$).

However, if $a\in A$ and $b\in B$,$$|a-b|\leqslant|a|+|b|\leqslant m+n.$$So,$$(\forall x\in A-B):|x|\leqslant m+n.$$

Comment: Do you mean  since sets A and B are bounded there exists an m, n such that |a|≤m for all a∈A and |b|≤n for all b∈B respectively. Then |a−b|⩽|a|+|b|⩽m+n.
So,
(∀x∈A−B):|x|⩽m+n. This proves that A-B is bounded?

Comment: That's my idea indeed.